# How to configure date facet filter with year granularity, when click it should show months

Tags: 7, search

I am using [Facet api](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi) with [Search api](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api).

I have enabled the facet for the node created date with Granularity set to "Year".

On the search page when I click on Year then it should show the months of that year and when click on month then it should display days of that month?

I didn't see any configurations for this in the facet configurations.

How will I achieve this functionality? Any contributed module?

Comment: You can check module [date facets](https://www.drupal.org/project/date_facets) maybe it will help you

Comment: it does not provide this functionality.

Comment: Maybe you can create there a feature request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution.

Just select the Granularity to "Days" instead of "Year" in the facet configurations.